# PARSE and SYNTAX ERROR

Tags: cakephp

i have this error displayed while working on my php code

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

on this line

```
if(isset('firstname','lastname','username','password','email'
```

Would appreciate if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget the variable name. In `isset` has to be variable(s), not strings. If I take an example with testing keys in `POST`, it should looks like:

```
if (isset($_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], ...)) {
    //
}
```

Generally with `$array`, $_POST can looks like something magic:

```
if (isset($array['firstname'], $array['lastname'], ...)) {
    //
}
```

Or you maybe want to test if variables exist, not keys in array. Then the code will be:

```
if (isset($firstname, $lastname, ...)) {
    //
}
```